# Get uploaded pictures of authenticated user facebook socialite laravel

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I am using laravel version 5.4.36 and i am using [Laravel Sociallite plugin](https://appdividend.com/2017/07/12/laravel-facebook-login/) to connect user with facebook.

I want to get uploaded pictures of logged in user as suggested in the [document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-user_photos) This is available through the photos edge on the User object.

```
public function redirect()
{
    //  return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
     return Socialite::driver('facebook')->fields([
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'gender', 'birthday','location','hometown','age_range','friends','posts','photos'
    ])->scopes([
        'email', 'user_birthday','user_gender','user_location','user_hometown',
        'user_age_range','user_friends','user_link','user_photos','user_posts',
        'user_tagged_places','user_videos','user_likes',
    ])->redirect();
}
```

In above code, I have requested

> user_photo as scope and photos as fields

[image]

my callback function is

```
public function callback(SocialFacebookAccountService $service)
{
    $user = $service->createOrGetUser(Socialite::driver('facebook')->fields([
        'name', 'email', 'birthday','gender','location','hometown','age_range','friends','link',
        'photos','posts','tagged_places','videos','likes',
    ])->user());
    auth()->login($user);
    return redirect()->to('/home');
}
```

where i have requested photos still i am not able to get photo age when i do

```
namespace App\Services;
use App\SocialFacebookAccount;
use App\User;
use Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\User as ProviderUser;
use File;

class SocialFacebookAccountService
{
    public function createOrGetUser(ProviderUser $providerUser)
    {
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($providerUser);die;

        $account = SocialFacebookAccount::whereProvider('facebook')
            ->whereProviderUserId($providerUser->getId())
            ->first();

        if ($account) {
            return $account->user;
        } else {

            $account = new SocialFacebookAccount([
                'provider_user_id' => $providerUser->getId(),
                'provider' => 'facebook'
            ]);

            $user = User::whereEmail($providerUser->getEmail())->first();
            //  echo "<pre>";print_r($user);die;

            if(!empty($providerUser->getAvatar())){
                $fileContents = file_get_contents($providerUser->getAvatar());
                File::put(public_path() . '/uploads/profile/' . $providerUser->getId() . ".jpg", $fileContents);
            }
             $imageUrl = $providerUser->getId() . ".jpg";
            // echo "<pre>";print_r($providerUser->user);die;
            if (!$user) {
                $user = User::create([
                    'email' => $providerUser->getEmail(),
                    'name' => $providerUser->getName(),
                    'password' => md5(rand(1,10000)),
                    'avatar'=> $imageUrl,
                    'birthday' => $providerUser->user['birthday'],
                    'gender' => $providerUser->user['gender'],
                    'age_range' =>$providerUser->user['age_range']['min'],
                    'total_friends'=>$providerUser->user['friends']['summary']['total_count'],
                    'profile_link'=>$providerUser->user['link'],
                ]);
            }

            $account->user()->associate($user);
            $account->save();

            return $user;
        }
    }
}
```

Have print in the starting of the `createOrGetUser` function but still i am not able to get photo age under the user object.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: Did you mean user_age_range? Those need extra permission and review too.

Comment: That means i wanted to get users uploaded pictures..

Comment: This statement " i am not able to get photo age when i do" you are trying to grab user profile picture right? Is it just returning empty node or any response error?

Comment: No no!! Profile picture is already i am getting.. I just wanted to get all uploaded pictures by the user.

Comment: Never tried it then. I am afraid I cannot help.