# Facebook - Invalid Scopes: manage_pages

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Can anyone help me to understand why i getting this error when i try to use Facebook SDK login button and ?

> Invalid Scopes: manage_pages. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

This is the HTML:

```
<fb:login-button scope="manage_pages" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></fb:login-button>
```

This is the JS:

```
    // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    window.facebook = {user_data: response};
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      testAPI();
      getUserPages();
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into your app or we are unable to tell.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    }
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '<app_id>',
      cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                          // the session
      xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
      version    : 'v2.12' // use graph api version 2.8
    });

    // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
    // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
    // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
    // the callback you provide.  They can be:
    //
    // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
    // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
    // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
    //    your app or not.
    //
    // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });

    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {
    showLog('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }  

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function getUserPages() {
   showLog('getUserPage');
    FB.api(
      '/'+window.facebook.user_data.authResponse.userID+'/accounts',
      'GET',
      {},
      function(response) {
          showLog(response);
          if (response.data != undefined && response.data.length > 0){
            window.facebook.user_data.pages = response.data
            getPagesReviews()
          }
      }
    );
  }
```

It's use to work like one month ago.
Thank for the help :)

Comment: Your app needs to be in dev mode now for that to work, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50970202/1427878 If you want to be able to ask anyone for those permissions in live mode, then you have to submit it for review first.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe

Answer (score 2):

just remove manage_pages from the scope and it will work

```
`<fb:login-button size="large" scope="public_profile,email,pages_show_list,read_insights,manage_pages" 
onlogin="checkLoginState();"> Click here to sync </fb:login-button>`
```

to

```
`<fb:login-button size="large" scope="public_profile,email,pages_show_list,read_insights" 
onlogin="checkLoginState();"> Click here to sync </fb:login-button>`
```

Comment: This is not the solution. It just removes what it could be grant permission.

Comment: Facebook regularly updates their permission policy... and it also depends upon the permission that Facebook has allowed you... so for me, as I checked these permissions were removed by Facebook as they introduced two new permissions instead of it... And removing this scope solved my issue... So before you give any downvotes to any of the answers ask them the solution description...